# Add a new user Identity value in Yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I need to assign a new variable to user identity like

```
 Yii::$app->user->identity->staff_name = 'myName';
```

I have added    `public $staff_name;` in the identityClass , which is usually `common\models\User`, but in my case is `common\models\Person`.

But when I print `Yii::$app->user->identity` the

```
Yii::$app->user->identity->staff_name value is blank.
```

Why it is blank ?

Comment: Have you changed identityClass in the components config?

Comment: yes, It is like 'user' => [
 
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\Person',

            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
            'identityCookie' => ['name' => '_identity-backend', 'httpOnly' => true],
        ],

Comment: 1. Assure that Yii::$app->user->identity is of proper class common\models\Person.

2. Assure that instances of common\models\Person allow setting of "staff_name" property externally (not from class's own methods)

3. Finally, assure that you set staff_name BEFORE checking/printing it. Just in case.

Comment: Are you setting (and checking) it _after_ login? You can try `Yii::$app->user->identity->canSetProperty('staff_name')` (although it seems you already know the answer). Does it work for other properties, like `id` or whatever you are using during authentication?

Comment: please mark the answer as correct if it helped you solving the problem so other having the same issue might also get help

Answer (score 1):

### `Steps to follow`

- You should add the public attribute `staff_name` to the `safe` rules

see below

```
public function rules(){
       return[
            [['staff_name'],'safe']
       ] ;
}
```

- If you are using **`dektrium/yii2-user`** use the following way to add to the parent rules

add to your `Person` model

```
public function rules() {
        return array_merge (parent::rules (), [ 'staff_nameSafe' => ['staff_name' , 'safe' ] ] );
    }
```

- Then you need to load this attribute manually too it won't have the value automatically like other model attributes which are the actual table fields so use `afterFind` in your `Person` model like below.

Note: i am using the hardcoded string `SAMPLE STAFF NAME` for the `staff_name` adjust it according to your needs

```
public function afterFind() {
    parent::afterFind ();
    $this->staff_name="SAMPLE STAFF NAME";
}
```

### `Test`

Now you can use `print_r(Yii::$app->user->identity->staff_name);` and it will print the name

```
SAMPLE STAFF NAME
```

Comment: which class do I need to add these ?

Comment: the class you are using as an identity i.e **`common\models\Person`** i think, you have specified in your question. @user7282

Comment: will afterFind() be invoked  automatically?

Comment: `afterFind()` is called when the AR object is created and populated with the query result.

The default implementation will trigger an `EVENT_AFTER_FIND` event. When overriding this method, make sure you call the parent implementation to ensure the event is triggered. @user7282

Comment: in above given method its `parent::afterFind ();` which invokes parent implementation.

Comment: but I also need to assign values after Yii::$app->user->identity has been set with the default values. Now Yii::$app->user->identity is null

Comment: what values you are talking about, the only thing required in your question was to be able to access a public property  `staff_name` defined inside the model via `Yii::$app->user->identity->staff_name` @user7282

Comment: After successful logging in, username will be set as identity. From that username value of identity, I need to call another function that will get staff_name value

Comment: sorry but, that wasnt any where in the question that you need to get the `staff_name` like this you can add  separate question for that. the current answer is for reflecting the value against the `staff_name` via `Yii::$app->user->identity`, whichever user identity class specified in the config. @user7282

Answer (score 0):

Using rules does not works for me
Instead i use a public parameter

```
public $staff_name='';
```

Then you can set it via afterfind like this

```
public function afterFind() {
    parent::afterFind ();
    $this->staff_name=\common\models\staff::findOne($this->staffid)->staffname;
}
```

Suppose you get staff name in your staff table, so

$this->staff_name is your public parameter
`\common\models\staff` is your models of staff table in common\models namespace

`$this->staffid` is your staff id in your user identity
staffname is your staff name field in your staff table

then you can use it like `Yii::$app->user->identity->staff_name`